# Proxmox 4 и ZFS

Tags: linux, proxmox, zfs

Есть внешняя хранилка подключенная к серверу. При использовании ZFS на ней происходят очень большие задержки(256 Гб ОЗУ на сервере ZFS ARC не ограничивали ни чем). В итоге VM "залипает" и помогает только перезагрузка VM.

Comment: Обоснуйте пожалуйста необходимость использования ZFS?      
На сколько "говорит" интернет крайне нестабильная работа с Linux. Более доступно написано **[тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/153461/)**

Comment: Добрый день. Обосновываю :-) https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Storage - в графе stable - yes. Помимо этого у проксмокса есть такая утилита - pve-zsync которая делает снэпшоты и у вас всегда будут свежие копии ваших виртуалок. А статья ваша извините от 2012 года.

Comment: Использую чистый KVM по отсутствию необходимости большого количества виртуалок, макс. 2-3. Судя по тому что вы описали, явно проблема именно с подключенным носителем, следом вопрос, когда виртуальная машина "зависает" вы анализировали сообщения ядра с dmesg? Я уверен вы увидите что-то интересное...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. да количество виртуалок большое, нам proxmox, на их форуме, в нашей ситуации порекомендовали чистый LVM(как следствие отсутствие клонов и снэпшотов). На каком то из форумов находил информацию что использовать ZFS и SAN не совсем правильно. В логах почти чисто)) только иногда "NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! " проскакивает когда ОЗУ почти все забирает ARC ZFS

Comment: Максимум чем смогу вам помочь, подсказать идею, как реализуете, это второй вопрос. Суть состоит в том, чтобы на момент снятия снапшота использовать промежуточный носитель включенный в ваш RAID, который на момент снятия снапшота вынимать из RAID. Тем самым когда будет процесс снятия, основной RAID "про это знать не будет". Это конечно не продакшн, но проблему может решить. А что будет этим носителем, файл образа или реальная железка, не важно.

Answer (score 1):

```
В чём проблема ограничить память для ZFS ARC ?
cat /etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf

# Min 512MB / Max 2048 MB Limit
options zfs zfs_arc_min=536870912
options zfs zfs_arc_max=2147483648
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что если дать ZFS ARC 2Гб, то он их всех и будет использовать, и это никак не решит вопроса с тормозами. Тут скорее проблема была в том, что кэш ZFS был быстрее внешней хранилки и когда он заполнялся потом выстраивалась очередь на запись на диски хранилища. Мы уже отказались от использования ZFS в этой конфигурации и проверить я не смогу правда ли это. Но как по мне вариант решения был бы SSD диски ну или использовать кэш в хранилке на запись, чтобы хоть как-то скорость сровнять.